# Disable a charfield in DJANGO when I'm creating a new User

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to do a crud in Django, it's about jefe and encargados. When I am logged in as an administrator, it has to allow me to create a encargados, but not a manager, but if I log in as a manager, it has to allow me to create a new encargados. For the jefe I am using a table called users and for the admin I am using the one from the Django admin panel.

Here are the models:

```
roles = (
('encargado', 'ENCARGADO'),
('jefe','JEFE'),
)
class Usuarios(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rol = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=roles, default='encargado')
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Meta: 
db_table = 'usuarios'
```

This is the create view

```
class UsuarioCrear(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Usuarios 
    form = Usuarios
    fields = "__all__"
    success_message = 'usuario creado correctamente !'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('leer')
```

This would be the html to create, here I put a restriction that the roles are only seen as administrator. but really what is necessary is that if I am as an administrator it only lets me select the jefe and if I am as a jefe it only lets me select encargados

```
            {% csrf_token %}
                <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id" class="txt_negrita">Id</label>                                  
                    {{ form.id|add_class:"form-control" }}
                </div>                                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="txt_negrita">Nombre</label>                                  
                    {{ form.nombre|add_class:"form-control" }}
                </div>       
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rol" class="txt_negrita">Rol</label>
                {{ form.rol|add_class:"form-control"}}
                </div>
    {%endif%}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="correo" class="txt_negrita">Correo</label>
                    {{ form.correo|add_class:"form-control" }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contraseña" class="txt_negrita">Contraseña</label>
                    {{ form.contraseña|add_class:"form-control" }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cedula" class="txt_negrita">Cedula</label>
                    {{ form.cedula|add_class:"form-control" }}
                </div> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
    <a href="../" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you need to get the user so you can pass it to the form via kwargs.  Add the following method to your view

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

Now in your form you can test against the user when you initialise the form

```
class Usuarios(forms.Form):

  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #use whatever method you need to determine options,
    # if self.user.is_staff: etc
    if self.user.rol == 'jefe':
        self.fields['rol'].choices = ('encargado', 'ENCARGADO'),
    else:
        self.fields['rol'].choices = ('jefe', 'JEFE'),
```